# For which algebras Taylor series and the Fourier series can be generalized?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion, fourier-series

I'm not a professional mathematician.
The question is in the title. But most of all I'd like to know about this for quaternions algebra with non commutative multiplication.

I'd like to know about truth of that expansions:

Q1. For functions with domain as catersian product of real numbers. And function range as some elements from rings, semirings algebra.

Q2. For function with domain, and range value from similar aglebra.

Comment: Can you add to your question an example (as precise or as rough as you like) of the kind of thing you'd like to see? Right now I'm not entirely sure what you want.

Comment: Example: We have function with domain Real number and Range as square matrices with det(M)!=0. Let's see on test function: F(T)=upper_trianlge_matrix_with_all_non_zero_values_set_to(t). Question: Can I use for such function taylor series?